# Create TableView in some UIView, Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

In my `ViewController` I have a little `UIView`. How do I programmatically create a `TableView` instead of this "blue" `UIView`.

I have this code for my `UIView`.

```
self.viewForTableView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,
                                                                 self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height,
                                                                 self.view.frame.size.width/2,
                                                                 self.view.frame.size.height)];
self.viewForTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.viewForTableView];
```

That's how I would like to have it [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a58Ep.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift

```
let tblVW:UITableView = UITableView(frame: viewForTableView.frame)
viewForTableView.addSubview(tblVW)
tblVW.delegate = self
tblVW.dataSource = self
```

Objective-c

```
 UITableView *tblView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:viewForTableView.frame];
[viewForTableView addSubview:tblView];
tblView.delegate = self;
tblView.dataSource = self;
```

you need to implement following methods:

```
#pragma mark - Table View Data source 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return 0//number rows you want in table
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
        UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2; //by default is 1
}
```

Comment: It`s not full answer. And it`s not work i need implement some methods, but unfortunately I don`t have so mach skills.

Comment: So what other methods do you need?

Comment: I think he talking about datasource and delegate methods

Comment: check following links [https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) [https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)

Answer (score 1):

**viewcontroller.h**

```
@interface yourViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

{
IBOutlet UITableView *tbleView;

}
```

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
tbleView.delegate=self;//for delegate methods 
tbleView.datasource=self;//for datasource methods
tbleView.backgroundColor=//yourColor
tbleView.frame=CGRectMake(//your frame);
[yourView addSubview tbleView];

}
```

Comment: you should not set frame in viewDidLoad!

Comment: It is necessary to give frame of table view.

Comment: Use `loadView` instead of `viewDidLoad`.